# How do Organic groups and virtual sites relate to each other?

Tags: organic-groups

I just want to know that a site which is built in [Openscholar](https://www.drupal.org/project/openscholar), a LMS for Drupal.

Therefore, how organic group is tied up with virtual sites? Also I want to know the the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module's role in such circumstances.

Comment: What's 'vsite'? There's no mention of such a thing on google in relation to Drupal

Comment: oh ho..i am metioned it above its in Drupal's lms "Openscolar"  . It creates a sperate site for a user under main site,a kind of subsite

Comment: does it mean virtual site?

Comment: yeah vsite means virtual site...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about openscholar but what organic modules can do about virtual sites-

- With help of organic group you can declare an entity as a "group" or call it context, an example could be a sports site with group as "cricket"
- With help of og you have permission granularity in context to group, so a user can have access to all post which comes under a "group" in our example "cricket" being totally unaware of other groups, can say "hockey"
- With in group you can have group specific roles, a user who can admin cricket group but still can not do anything on hockey group.

So each group can be seen as fully functional site in itself - virtual site

**Note: Domains have nothing to do with og, it's just a matter of context switching**

Comment: yeah...exactly...

Comment: does that answer your question?

Comment: yeah lots of it is the answer...but i want to find out how organic groups are related to vsite(virtual site). I want to know the basic architecture of organic group and vsite.

Answer (score 1):

As a variation of what's explained in the prior answer, you could also use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module for this (instead of the [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module). [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. So each group can be seen as fully functional site in itself, i.e. a virtual site.

It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable. So since Group is entirely entity based, it has out-of-the-box integrations (= no extra modules needed) with other great modules such as [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), etc.

For more details about the various roles and permissions, refer to my answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)".

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".

Comment: Seems that it will work  !! let me implement first.

Comment: @RajenderRajan : merci for feedback ... and yes I think you will like what you will discover ... looking forward to your evaluation later on ...!

Comment: defiantly m experimenting something ! Once done i will let u kw whole idea .

Comment: @RajenderRajan Did you make any progress in your experimenting?

Comment: Openscholar by default provides a vsite for a particular user..M just wanted to use Rules module, organic module and Views to customize  the work flow of Openscholar. Till nothing much has been results, i have tried different approaches but just fail to get desired result.